# How do I use leather?

Tags: starbound

I've farmed a lot of leather, but I don't see any recipe with it. How can I use that?
Or maybe, it just still hasn't recipes during beta?

Comment: Probably just no recipes yet, I've been wondering this as well. My guess is it'll probably be introduced in a new recipe soon since Tiy wants to get in 1-2 tiers of content per week.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Leather can be used to make Snow Infantry Armor at the Spinning Wheel. This armor has a very high warmth value making it useful for exploring cold planets and moons.

Comment: But I haven't any recipe with leather at Spinning Wheel. How can I research that?

Comment: Make sure the 'materials available' checkbox at the bottom of the list is unchecked if you can't see it, there is no research required to get the recipe.

Comment: It is, I am sure, but I haven't checked the last update still, so...

Comment: Snow Armor is also handy for exploring the asteroid minibiome, although you'll still need plenty of torches or other sources of warmth.