# How do I protect myself against cold weather on the surface?

Tags: starbound

I'm currently on a very cold planet having trouble staying warm. I find myself placing a campfire every screen-width I travel just to keep myself from dying. Are there better ways to stay warm, particularly early in the game?

Comment: Building a house (or operating underground) provides warmth, out of experimentation. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Thomas Houses don't seem to help, and I haven't been able to get far down enough - the enemies here are too hard.

Comment: Do you have any leather? You can use it to make armor that can help keep you warm: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/144937/30210

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a set of craftable clothing that you can make at the Spinning Wheel. Snow Infantry Gear.  The flavor text suggests that it protects against cold weather.

The problem being it requires leather to craft, a total of 38 pieces for the whole set.  Leather is somewhat hard to come by due to a low drop rate.  I suggest heading out and hunting down animals with an iron hunting bow until you get enough leather for that gear.

Comment: I'll try that out, I have exactly 23 leather to begin with, so it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Luckily for me I had 57 leather when the patch hit ;)

Comment: It's more than 23 for the whole set by the way, but it works great.

Comment: While the answer remains clothing, I do believe that the Iron+ tier armor also starts helping with cold resistance.

Comment: @James It does, but not nearly enough for most cold planets.

Answer (score 1):

I have the Snow Infantry Gear it has decent defense at lower levels and has very high resistance to the cold. The leather doesn't take very long on a level one planet if you have an Iron Bow, the bow should kill everything in one hit so collecting leather isn't too bad.

Comment: Does this add anything besides confirming the other answer?

Answer (score 1):

higher level armour is warmer, but it takes more time to get than infantry snow armour.